# SQL Server Container Hanging on Windows 11 Pro

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I am creating a Docker image for a SQL Server database and an ASP.Net Core 6.0 application.

To create a Docker Configuration file as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY /bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ SportsStore/
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
ENV Logging__Console__FormatterName=Simple
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /SportsStore
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SportsStore.dll", "--urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Next, we're instructed to create a yaml file with the following content:

```
version: "3"
services:
    sportsstore:
        build: .
        ports:
           - "5000:5000"
        environment:
           - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
        depends_on:
           - sqlserver
    sqlserver:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
          SA_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxxx"
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Next, we're instructed to publish the application as follows:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

And perform the Docker build:

```
docker-compose build
```

And finally starting the database container:

```
docker-compose up sqlserver
```

At this point, the container appears to be starting however after some time, the process seems to be unresponsive and an hangs here:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be alot of information on this specific error, however did update the connection string as follows:

From this:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
       "SportsStoreConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore; MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
       "IdentityConnection"   : "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Identity;    MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

To this:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
     "SportsStoreConnection": "Server=localhost\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore; MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
     "IdentityConnection": "Server=localhost\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Identity;    MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Chance the `Server` in the connection strings to `sqlserver` . There's no error message in the screenshot, the server started succesfully. The *connection strings* are wrong. LocalDB is an embedded database that comes as a feature of SQL Server Express, used almost exclusively for development and testing. You don't need it at all if you have a full database server running in a separate container. You *can't* use is either unless you install SQL Server Express on the same container as the application.

Comment: BTW you'll have to specify the username and password either in the connection string or in code.

Comment: Currently the db is using Windows Authentication.  Does it still need a user/pwd?

Comment: You can't use Windows Authentication in a Linux container without setting up Kerberos, essentially joining both the web container and the database to an AD Domain

Comment: SQL Server for Linux, and thus also the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server Docker containers, do not have an SQL Browser service which means that you cannot use instance names in the connection strings that reference them. i.e.: instead of `Server=sqlserver\\AnyInstanceNameAtAllHere;` just use `Server=sqlserver;`. If it doesn't resolve that name try adding `container_name: sqlserver` to the service definition's properties in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I'm new to Docker so not understanding how Linux is factoring into the comments here since I'm creating the container on a Win 11 Pro box.

Comment: Nevermind..found this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash#buildnonrootcontainer